# Error while installing/building ruby listen on Debian Wheezy

Tags: rubygems, sass, debian

I'd just start with saying that it feels like there should be something written on the topic already, but I have not managed to find anything so feel free to redirect me.

So, I was going to use [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) with watch

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

Which told me I needed to install listen, but when I do so I get a build error.

```
victor@Minos:~$ sudo gem install listen
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing listen:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.9.0/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
```

System

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ uname -a
Linux Minos 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just sorted it out, just needed `ruby1.9.1-dev`

```
$ sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev
```

Comment: It looks like you just saved me 1 hour and 11 minutes. Thank you for posting back with the answer!